How to Flash a Sample Talker to ESP32 Without Using Docker or Building the Full Micro-ROS Source Code?
I'm trying to flash a sample talker to an ESP32 using Micro-ROS, but I want to avoid using Docker or building the entire Micro-ROS source code.
Is there a straightforward way to achieve this, possibly by using precompiled binaries or minimal tools? Detailed steps or pointers to relevant instructions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
